# What to do if insulation is too thick?

Tags: insulation

I was careless with an insulation order (months ago, non returnable AFIAK). I bought faced batts of R-30, labeled as 10 inches thick for my garage. However, my garage framed with regular 2x4.

How much will the R-value go down if I compress those batts in there? Is it better to just tear them all in half?

If the context helps:

The garage will be heated (and possibly cooled) so I can work on it a couple hours a few days a week year round. And I want to keep my tools and materials from freezing, of course. I intend on **keeping** it heated to ~55 F in the winter and cooling to 78 or so in the summer **as-needed.**

Comment: Do not compress.  Either use then in the ceiling(very good), add more depth to the walls~2x6s(good), or split them in half(okay).

Comment: Rather than get substandard performance from the wrong thing, I suggest selling the material on Craigslist or Facebook Marketplace and buying the right stuff.

Comment: You might get better insulative value / less than the R-30 but more than what the 2x4 stuff would get you.  While you'd think that they've designed the thickness for best R-value they haven't.  https://www.energyvanguard.com/blog/compressed-fiberglass-insulation-really-so-bad/

Comment: We built our house with 10” of insulation - insulation can never be too thick. Nice low heating bills and cool in summer.

Comment: Would add to your question what you planning on doing with the garage.  Heated or unheated, work in there for hours or just keep a car in it?

Comment: Added context. But, I'm assuming splitting the stuff will cut it's R value in half. And, I'm mostly curious whether compressing it will beat that.

Answer (score 2):

Compressing batts will yield higher R per inch than splitting it.

A compressed batt will have lower R in a given cavity.

So, don't needlessly compress, but do compress if you need to fit a thicker batt into a shallower cavity.

> standard low-density batts, at their nominal rated thickness — R-11 at 3 1/2 inches, or R-19 at 6 inches — have an R-value of about 3.1 per inch. If you compress a 6-inch R-19 batt into a 3 1/2-inch cavity, you get about R-14, or 4.0 per inch. This is a much higher R-value per inch, but the total value of R-14 is still substantially less than the R-19 you started with. Even in a 5 1/2-inch wall, the R-19 (which is rated at 6 inches of thickness) gives you only R-18.

From https://www.jlconline.com/how-to/insulation/q-a-compressing-fiberglass-batts_o

And also

[image]

From https://insulationinstitute.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Compressed_R_values.pdf